# How to delete The Request body and add a new one, Request object in RestSharp v1.07+ C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, restsharp, webapi

I added a
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), ParameterType.RequestBody);  or by
request.AddJsonBody(body, "application/json"); to the request object They work.

How to delete this body from the request object and add a new one (or update it -if it is possible) instead of recreating the request object again and again just to change the body element.
RestSharp V107+
I tried request.Parameters.RemoveParameter("body"); It did not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to look in the parameters to find the existing `BodyParameter` then remove it from the request and replace with a new one (if applicable).

```
var bodyParameter = request.Parameters.OfType<BodyParameter>().Single();
// optional: verify if needed this is the body you want to replace
request.RemoveParameter(bodyParameter)
    .AddJsonBody(yourNewBody);
```